# .net publish to prover creates 'unwanted' role

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am using the publish to provider feature in .net 2008 to produce a database creation script.

In the script exists the following line:

```
/****** Object:  Role [srvTTAS]    Script Date: 01/20/2010 09:14:14 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'srvTTAS')
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'srvTTAS' AND type = 'R')
CREATE ROLE [srvTTAS]
```

This causes a problem as I have a USER called "srvTTAS" setup in my database, and not a role.  So when I run this script I have to manually delete the role in order to create a user of the same name.  This means the script produced does not create a exact copy of the database in question, is there a way to make publish to provider create a user? (as I have specified in the database?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of any "[principal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328(SQL.90).aspx)" in the database must be unique. Roles and users are both principals.

Does this publisher have a bug?
Or perhaps it can't distinguish principals correctly (for example, Metadata visibility)?

Anyhow, what are using srvTTAS for? For permissioning, it should be a role anyway with your database user in the role.

Comment: I am using srvTTAS for permissioning (uid=srvTTAS in my connectionstring) 
Can you put a role in a connectionstring?

Comment: hmmm, ok will have to continue to edit the script each time then, what a pain.

(I have looked into using Kerberos, but that proved problematic in our environment - so I went as simple as I could on security)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the first SELECT statement is missing  `AND type = 'R'`